# In a transitive action there is a bijection between the fixed points of a stabilizer of a and the lateral clases of the stabilizer in his normalizer

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

the question is the given above, specially in the case infinite:

If the action of $G$ is transitive, then there is a bijection between the fixed points of the stabilizer of a element $a$ and the lateral classes of the stabilizer of $a$ in the normalizer of the stabilizer of $a$?.

My bijection is $G_{ah}$(this denotes a lateral class of the stabilizer of a) to $ha$ where $a$ is the point of the stabilizer, this function is well-defined and is one to one. Since $G$ acts transitively then all point $y$ is equal to a $ga$ with $g \in G$, and if this is in the fixed points then the $g$ is such that the conjugate of $G_a$ is contained in $G_a$. In orden to prove that the function is a surjection, i need that the $g$ given above normalizes $G_a$, and this is precisely the problem. I can assure something about the $g$?

Thank you for the further answers

Comment: I don't think that it's very clear what you're asking here, could you please clarify?

Comment: The exercise is the 1.6.3 in the book Permutation Groups of Dixon and Mortimer

Comment: My bijection is G_ah to ha where a is the point of the stabilizer, this function is well-defined and is one to one. Since G acts transitively then all point y is equal to a ga with g in G, and if this is in the fixed points then the g is such that the conjugate of G_a is contained in G_a. In orden to prove that the function is a surjection, i need that the g given above normalizes G_a, and this is precisely the problem. I can assure something about the g?

Answer (score 1):

**Addendum** OP made me realize that in the finite case there is a fine point here. So I believe that in the general case the bijection asked for does not involve the normalizer
$$
N_{G}(G_{\alpha}) = \{ g \in G : g G_{\alpha} g^{-1} =  G_{\alpha} \},
$$
but the related object
$$
\tilde{N}_{G}(G_{\alpha}) = \{ g \in G : g G_{\alpha} g^{-1} \subseteq  G_{\alpha} \}.
$$
Note that $\tilde{N}_{G}(G_{\alpha})$ is a submonoid of $G$, but need not be a subgroup of $G$. (I will provide an example later.) It coincides with the normalizer, and thus it is a subgroup, if $G$ is finite, or a torsion group.

---

Let $G$ act transitively on a set $A$, let $a \in A$, and let $B$ the set of points fixed by $G_{a}$.

Let $b \in B$. Then there exists $g$ such that $a g = b$. Let $h \in G_{a}$. Then $a g h = b h = b = a g$, so that $g h g^{-1} \in G_{a}$. In other words, $g \in \tilde{N}_{G}(G_{a})$.

Conversely, if $g \in \tilde{N}_{G}(G_{a})$, then $b = a g$ is fixed by $G_{a}$.

Now we are ready to set the correspondence. Start with the map
$$
\tilde{N}_{G}(G_{a}) \to B
$$
given by $g \mapsto a g$. We have shown that this is surjective.

Now $a g = a g'$ if and only if $g' g^{-1} \in G_{a}$, so this yields a bijection as requested between the cosets of $G_{a}$ in $\tilde{N}_{G}(G_{a})$ and $B$.

---

**Addendum: an example** Consider the additive abelian group $$A = \Bbb{Z}\left[ \dfrac{1}{2}\right] = \left\{ \dfrac{z}{2^{n}} : z \in \Bbb{Z}, n \ge 0 \right\}.$$ Let $c$ be the automorphism of $A$ given by $a \mapsto 2 a$, and let $G = A \langle c \rangle$ be the natural semidirect product.

Let $H = \Bbb{Z} \le A$, and consider the action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$. Let $\alpha = H$. Then $G_{\alpha} = H$. Now $N_{G}(G_{\alpha}) = A$, whereas $\tilde{N}_{G}(G_{\alpha})$ is the submonoid generated by $A$ and $c$, that is
$$\tilde{N}_{G}(G_{\alpha}) = \{ a c^{n} : a \in A, n \ge 0 \}.$$

Comment: But the first condition only gives that the conjugate for g of the normalizator is contained in the normalizator, but the equality not necessarily holds if G is a infinite group and hence g not necessarily is a element of the normalizator

Comment: @user78594, sorry, I don't get you. What is the *first condition*, and which *equality* does not necessarily hold?

Comment: The first condition is such that for every h in the stabilizator the conjugate for g of h is also in the stabilizator, and the equality is the equality of the stabilizator and the conjugate of the stabilizator for g. The first condition only gives that the conjugate is contained in the stabilizator.

Comment: @user78594, I finally got it, sorry for having been sluggish. I think you are right, and that one should replace the normalizer with $\tilde{N}_{G}(G_{\alpha}) = \{ g \in G : g G_{\alpha} g^{-1} \subseteq G_{\alpha} \}$. This is only a submonoid, not a subgroup in general, but I'd say it is the correct object in the general (infinite) case.

Comment: OK thank you, Is there a counterexample for the required bijection?